# The boundary of a singleton in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Is the boundary of a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ just that same subset once again, and if so how does this mesh with the definition of small/large inductive dimension for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

If $Bd(X)=\overline{X}\setminus intX$ and finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed with empty interior this seems to be the case, but then the definition for the small inductive dimension of a point fails to yield dimension $0$ since the boundary of the point is itself and not the empty set.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are supposed to compute boundary in the set for which you are computing the dimension. If you want to compute the dimension of a singleton $X=\{p\}$, then every neighborhood $U$ containing $p$ is $U=X$. An open set containing $x$ with closure inside $U$, would again be $X$. Since $X$ is open an closed in itself, then its boundary is empty. Since the empty set has dimension $-1$, then $X$ has dimension $0$.

Comment: You can continue this to then compute the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$. For every point $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and every neighborhood $U\ni p$, you can put inside a closed interval $[p-r,p+r]\subset U$, with $r>0$. Then the boundary of the open set $(p-r,p+r)$, boundary that we compute as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ because that is the space that we are computing its dimension, would be $\{p-r, p+r\}$. Since the set with two points has dimension $0$, then $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: @deyore Ah, thank you -- so we essentially work in the subspace topology at each boundary in the recursion when computing its dimension?

Comment: Yes, the dimension of a boundary will be computed as a space with the induced topology.

Comment: @deyore Much appreciated!

Comment: The boundary of a finite subset of $\Bbb R$ is itself because $\Bbb R$ is a $T_1$ space with no isolated points. This does not tell us anything about the small inductive dimension (ind)   Other examples of $T_1$ spaces with no isolated points : The Cantor set (ind$=0$),.... $\Bbb R^n$ (ind$=n$)... Hilbert space (ind$=\infty$).

Comment: @deyore Haven't you only technically shown in your previous comment that $ind\mathbb{R}\leq1$?  How do we show that $ind\mathbb{R}>0$? Observe that the boundary of an arbitrary neighborhood would have to be empty and the only clopen sets in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ itself, and these are precisely the sets with empty boundary to get a contradiction?

Comment: We already showed that the dimension of a point (actually we need of the disjoint union of two points, but it is the same computation) is zero. Just follow [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension) inside every neighborhood of a point in $\mathbb{R}$ there is an open interval containing the point such that the closure of the interval is also inside the neighborhood. By the definition we only need to compute the dimension of the boundary of that interval (the $V$ in the link), which is a pair of points. For all the cases, the dimension is zero. Therefore $n=0+1$ is ...

Comment: ... the smallest. Smaller than that you would need a $V$ such that its boundary has dimension $-1$. The boundary would have to be empty. The only subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that have empty boundary are the empty set, or the whole $\mathbb{R}$. The first one is not a neighborhood of any point, the second cannot be fit inside $U$ unless $U$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.